# Rearrange an array of objects based on a common key/value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

I have the following array of objects:

```
[
   {
     message: 'This is a test',
     from_user_id: 123,
     to_user_id: 567
   },
   {
     message: 'Another test.',
     from_user_id: 123,
     to_user_id: 567
   },
   {
     message: 'A third test.',
     from_user_id: '456',
     to_user_id: 567
   }
]
```

How do I construct a new array of objects where the outermost object key is based on a common key found in the original array?

This is what I'm after:

```
[
  {
    123: [
      {
        message: 'This is a test',
        from_user_id: 123,
        to_user_id: 567
      },
      {
        message: 'Another test.',
        from_user_id: 123,
        to_user_id: 567
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    456: [
      {
        message: 'A third test.',
        from_user_id: '456',
        to_user_id: 567
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Notice how in the first array, the user ID of `123` shows up in two objects.  That would be the object key for the first element in the new array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an object and take the `from_user_id` property as key for the object. Then push the actual object to the group. For getting the final result, iterate the keys of `groups` and build a new object for any group.

```js
var data = [{ message: 'This is a test', from_user_id: 123, to_user_id: 567 }, { message: 'Another test.', from_user_id: 123, to_user_id: 567 }, { message: 'A third test.', from_user_id: '456', to_user_id: 567 }],
    groups = Object.create(null),
    result;

data.forEach(function (a) {
    groups[a.from_user_id] = groups[a.from_user_id] || [];
    groups[a.from_user_id].push(a);    
});

result = Object.keys(groups).map(function (k) {
    var temp = {};
    temp[k] = groups[k];
    return temp;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Together with a single loop approach

```js
var data = [{ message: 'This is a test', from_user_id: 123, to_user_id: 567 }, { message: 'Another test.', from_user_id: 123, to_user_id: 567 }, { message: 'A third test.', from_user_id: '456', to_user_id: 567 }],
    result = data.reduce(function (groups) {
        return function (r, a) {
            var temp = {};
            if (!groups[a.from_user_id]) {
                groups[a.from_user_id] = [];
                temp[a.from_user_id] = groups[a.from_user_id]; 
                r.push(temp);
            }
            groups[a.from_user_id].push(a);
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can you explain how is this works => *`groups[a.from_user_id] = groups[a.from_user_id] || [];`*

Comment: if the key `a.from_user_id` does not exist in the object, it returns `undefined` and then the default value, an empty array is taken and assigned. the `||` is a logical OR, sometimes called *default operator*.

Comment: Since you cannot `.push()` on `undefined` but only on an array empty or not, we need to ensure that the `groups[...]` is either something or an empty list.

Comment: Nice approach, but this will return an object and not an array!!! The OP wants to have an array as results.

Comment: @NinaScholz Well done, it's really a piece of art :)

Comment: @NinaScholz, such an awesome answer.  And thanks for showing the first approach (returning an object)!

`groups[message.from_user_id] = groups[message.from_user_id] || []` sets up the object’s key, where `message.from_user_id` is the key if it exists, and an empty array if it does not exist.  To set up the value, it looks like you’re doing `groups[message.from_user_id].push(message)`, which I’m not really familiar with.  I thought `.push()` could only be expected on an array.  Isn’t `groups[message.from_user_id]` just an object key (with an empty value)?

Comment: Since the second method only contains one loop, is it more performant?

Comment: @Farid, if you take the value of an object with a keys, which does not exist, then you get `undefined` and that is a falsy value for the check with the coming logical OR `||`. in this case an empty array is assigned as a property of the object. the later push works then with this array. depending on implementation, a single loop is better if there are no other loops involved.

Answer (score 4):

You could go full functional get all the key filter it out and map it back as a json object

```
var b = a.map(key => key['from_user_id'])
var c = {}
b.map(elt => c[elt] = a.filter(k => k.from_user_id == elt))
console.log(c)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Even though there are two loops, it's done in [what seems like] fewer lines of code, which is always great.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var users = [
             {
               message: 'This is a test',
               from_user_id: 123,
               to_user_id: 567
             },
             {
               message: 'Another test.',
               from_user_id: 123,
               to_user_id: 567
             },
             {
               message: 'A third test.',
               from_user_id: '456',
               to_user_id: 567
             }
          ];
console.log(_.groupBy(users,'from_user_id'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Using [Lodash](http://lodash.com) will make it super easy for you. Assuming you have :

```
var users = [
             {
               message: 'This is a test',
               from_user_id: 123,
               to_user_id: 567
             },
             {
               message: 'Another test.',
               from_user_id: 123,
               to_user_id: 567
             },
             {
               message: 'A third test.',
               from_user_id: '456',
               to_user_id: 567
             }
          ];
```

just in one line with `Lodash` and **you'll get want you want exactly**:

```
users = _.groupBy(users,'from_user_id')
```

Comment: I did not try using Lodash because I was attempting to do this in vanilla JS, but this is definitely good to know!  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome ! should give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to initialize a `results` array, loop over your data array and check if the iterated `from_user_id` exists in the `results` array, push the iterated object on it, otherwise create a new object with the new `from_user_id` key.

This is how should be your code:

```
var results = [];
arr.forEach(function(obj){
    let id = obj["from_user_id"];
    if(!results.some(function(r){
       return r[id];
    })){
        let el = {}; 
        el[id] = [];
        el[id].push(obj);
        results.push(el);
    }else{
        results.forEach(function(res){
            if(res[id]){
              res[id].push(obj);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var arr = [{
  message: 'This is a test',
  from_user_id: 123,
  to_user_id: 567
}, {
  message: 'Another test.',
  from_user_id: 123,
  to_user_id: 567
}, {
  message: 'A third test.',
  from_user_id: 456,
  to_user_id: 567
}];


var results = [];
arr.forEach(function(obj){
    let id = obj["from_user_id"];
    if(!results.some(function(r){
       return r[id];
    })){
        let el = {}; 
        el[id] = [];
        el[id].push(obj);
        results.push(el);
    }else{
        results.forEach(function(res){
            if(res[id]){
              res[id].push(obj);
            }
        });
    }
});
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thanks! :)  I was sort of trying to avoid a double loop, but it seems to be the most common way.